# Coding something about a rectangle (Java)

Tags: java

so in my online class I have to do something related to rectangles. I have some confusion on how to edit my main class to make it use a method from another class.

Here is the link of the project just incase you don't understand what I'm going to ask:
 http://pages.eimacs.com/eimacsstatics/download/apjava/project1bj.pdf

The part I'm confused about is adding a definition for printAPRectangle, because I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

> Add accessor instance methods for the three instance variables, and then
>   click the Compile button on the APRectangle class editor window to compile
>   your code and check for errors.
>
> Reopen the definition of MainClass and insert a definition of the static
>   method printAPRectangle after the definition of printAPPoint. This method
>   should be defined in such a way that, if it is applied to the APRectangle
>   object whose top left corner is the APPoint object with coordinate (-5.0,3.6),

Here is my APRectangle class code:

```
    public class APRectangle
   {
    private APPoint myTopLeft;
    private double  myWidth;
    private double  myHeight;

    public APRectangle( APPoint topLeft, double width, double height )
    {
        myTopLeft = topLeft;
        myWidth = width;
        myHeight = height;
    }

    public APPoint getTopLeft()
    {
        return myTopLeft;
    }

    public double getWidth()
    {
        return myWidth;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return myHeight;
    }
}
```

Here is my APPoint class:

> public class APPoint {
>       private double myX;
>       private double myY;
>
> ```
> public APPoint( double x, double y )  {
>  myX = x;
>  myY = y;  }
> public double getX()   {
> return myX;  }
> public void setX( double x )  {
>  myX = x;  }
> public double getY()  {
>  return myY;  }
> public void setY( double y )  {
>  myY = y;  } }
> ```

and finally here is my Main Class:

```
public class MainClass
{
 public MainClass()
 {
    }

 public static String printAPPoint( APPoint p )
 {
     return "(" + p.getX() + "," + p.getY() + ")";
    }

 public static String printAPRectangle( APRectangle R)
 {
     return "[APRectangle " + printAPPoint( +
            " " + getWidth() + "," + getHeight() + "]" ;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     APPoint p = new APPoint( 1.0, 2.0 );
     APRectangle R = new APRectangle( q, 7.5, 3.6);
     System.out.println( "p is " + printAPPoint( p ) );
     System.out.println( "Done!" );
  }

}
```

I don't know how to do the part that asks me how to edit the main class, and also the part where I have to output myTopLeft because it's an APPoint and not a normal string. It says I have to use printAPPoint but how do i use it?

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Why don't you add system.out.prinltln("R is " + printAPRectangle(R)); to your main() method?

Comment: Um, I did that but I changed my main class so basically in the main it says APRectangle R = new APRectangle( p, 7.5, 3.6 ) so my problem is in the method printAPRectangle is that I don't know how to get the printAPPoint(p) to work. because I get an error saying variable p cannot be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use APRectangle's methods, you must call them from an APRectangle object.
The printAPRectangle method receives an APRectangle object called R.
You must use R and call it's member functions.
You need to use these:

- R.getTopLeft()
- R.getWidth()
- R.getHeight()

  public static String printAPRectangle( APRectangle R)
  {
  return "[APRectangle " + printAPPoint(R.getTopLeft) +
  " " + R.getWidth() + "," + R.getHeight() + "]" ;
  }

Comment: Are you really using BlueJ? I was able to avoid BlueJ when I started learning Java in 2007.

Comment: My course shows examples in BlueJ so I just used it. Didn't know how to use Eclipse or whatever so... yes I really am using BlueJ.